# How do I match a hex array in perl6 grammar

Tags: regex, grammar, raku

I have a string like `"39 3A 3B  9:;"` and i want to extract "39, 3A, 3B"

I have tried

```
my $a = "39 3A 3B  9:;";
grammar Hex {
    token TOP { <hex_array>+ .* }
    token hex_array { <[0..9 A..F]> " " }
};
Hex.parse($a);
```

But this doesn't seem to work.
And even this doesn't seem to work.

```
my $a = "39 3A 3B ";
grammar Hex {
    token TOP { <hex_array>+ }
    token hex_array { <[0..9 A..F]> " " }
};
Hex.parse($a);
```

I did try Grammar::Tracer both TOP and hex_array fail

```
TOP
|  hex_array
|  * FAIL
* FAIL
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`<[abcdef...]>` in a P6 regex is a "character class" in the match-*one*-character sense.<sup>1</sup>

The idiomatic way to get what you want is to use [the `**` quantifier](https://docs.perl6.org/language/regexes#index-entry-regex_quantifier_**-General_quantifier%3A_**_min..max):

```
my $a = "39 3A 3B ";
grammar Hex {
  token TOP { <hex_array>+ }
  token hex_array { <[0..9 A..F]>**1..2 " " }
};
Hex.parse($a);
```

---

The rest of this answer is "bonus" material on why and how to use `rule`s.

You are of course perfectly free to match whitespace situations by including whitespace patterns in arbitrary individual tokens, like you did with `" "` in your `hex_array` token.

However, it's good practice to use [`rule`s](https://docs.perl6.org/language/grammars#index-entry-declarator_rule-Rules) instead when appropriate -- which is most of the time.

## First, use `ws` instead of " ", `\s*` etc.

Let's remove the space in the second `token` and move it instead to the first one:

```
  token TOP { [ <hex_array> " " ]+ }
  token hex_array { <[0..9 A..F]>**1..2 }
```

We've added square bracketing (`[...]`) that combines the `hex_array` and a space and then applied the `+` quantifier to that combined atom. It's a simple change, and the grammar continues to work as before, matching the space as before, except now the space won't be captured by the `hex_array` token.

Next, let's switch to using the built in [`ws`](https://docs.perl6.org/language/grammars#ws) `token`:

```
  token TOP { [ <hex_array> <.ws> ]+ }
```

The default `<ws>` is more generally useful, in desirable ways, than `\s*`.<sup>2</sup> And if the default `ws` doesn't do what you need you can specify your own `ws` token.

We've used `<.ws>` instead of `<ws>` because, like `\s*`, use of `<.ws>` avoids additional capture of whitespace that would likely just clutter up the parse tree and waste memory.

One often wants something like `<.ws>` after almost every token in higher level parsing rules that string tokens together. But if it were just explicitly written like that it would be highly repetitive and distracting `<.ws>` and `[ ... <.ws> ]` boilerplate. To avoid that there's a built in shortcut for *implicitly* expressing a default assumption of inserting the boilerplate for you. This shortcut is the `rule` declarator, which in turn uses `:sigspace`.

## Using `rule` (which uses `:sigspace`)

A `rule` is *exactly* the same as a `token` except that it switches on [`:sigspace`](https://docs.perl6.org/language/regexes#index-entry-regex_adverb_%3Asigspace-regex_adverb_%3As-Sigspace) at the start of the pattern:

```
rule  {           <hex_array>+ }
token { :sigspace <hex_array>+ } # exactly the same thing
```

*Without* `:sigspace` (so in `token`s and `regex`s by default), *all* literal spaces in a pattern (unless you quote them) are *ignored*. This is generally desirable for readable patterns of individual *`token`s* because they typically specify literal things to match.

But once `:sigspace` is in effect, spaces **after** atoms become "significant" -- because they're implicitly converted to `<.ws>` or `[ ... <.ws> ]` calls. This is desirable for readable patterns specifying sequences of tokens or subrules because it's a natural way to avoid the clutter of all those extra calls.

The first pattern below will match one or more `hex_array` tokens with no spaces being matched either between them or at the end. The last two will match one or more `hex_array`s, without intervening spaces, and then *with or without* spaces at the very end:

```
  token TOP {           <hex_array>+ }
  #          ^ ignored ^            ^ ignored

  token TOP { :sigspace <hex_array>+ }
  #          ^ ignored ^            ^ significant

  rule TOP  {           <hex_array>+ }
  #          ^ ignored ^            ^ significant
```

**NB.** Adverbs (like `:sigspace`) aren't atoms. Spaces immediately **before** the first *atom* (in the above, spaces *before* `<hex_array>`) are **never** significant (regardless of whether `:sigspace` is or isn't in effect). But thereafter, if `:sigspace` is in effect, all non-quoted spacing in the pattern is "significant" -- that is, it's converted to `<.ws>` or `[ ... <.ws> ]`.

In the above code, the second token and the rule would match a *single* `hex_array` with spaces after it because the space immediately after the `+` and before the `}` means the pattern is rewritten to:

```
  token TOP { <hex_array>+ <.ws> }
```

But this rewritten token *won't* match if your input has *multiple* `hex_array` tokens with one or more spaces *between* them. Instead you would want to write:

```
  rule TOP { <hex_array> + }
  # ignored ^           ^ ^ both these spaces are significant
```

which is rewritten to:

```
  token TOP { [ <hex_array> <.ws> ]+ <.ws> }
```

This will match your input.

## Conclusion

So, after all that apparent complexity, which is really just me being exhaustively precise, I'm suggesting you might write your original code as:

```
my $a = "39 3A 3B ";
grammar Hex {
  rule TOP { <hex_array> + }
  token hex_array { <[0..9 A..F]>**1..2 }
};
Hex.parse($a);
```

and this would match more flexibly than your original (I'm presuming that would be a good thing though of course it might not be for some use cases) and would perhaps be easier to read for most P6ers.

Finally, to reinforce how to avoid two of the three gotchyas of `rule`s, see also [What's the best way to be lax on whitespace in a perl6 grammar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56507066/whats-the-best-way-to-be-lax-on-whitespace-in-a-perl6-grammar). (The third gotchya is whether you need to put a space between an atom and a quantifier, as with the space between the `<hex_array>` and the `+` in the above.)

## Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> If you want to match multiple characters, then append a suitable quantifier to the character class. This is a sensible way for things to be, and [the assumed behavior of a "character class" according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Character_classes). Unfortunately the P6 doc currently confuses the issue, eg lumping together both genuine character classes and other rules that match multiple characters under the heading [Predefined character classes](https://docs.perl6.org/language/regexes#Predefined_character_classes).

<sup>2</sup> The default `ws` rule is designed to match *between words*, where a "word" is a contiguous sequence of letters (Unicode category L), digits (Nd), or underscores. In code, it's specified as:

```
regex ws { <!ww> \s* }
```

`ww` is a "within word" test. So `<!ww>` means *not* within a "word". `<ws>` will always succeed where `\s*` would -- except that, unlike `\s*`, it *won't* succeed in the middle of a word. (Like any other atom quantified with a `*`, a plain `\s*` will always match because it matches any number of spaces, including *none at all*.)

Comment: As a side note this turned out to be really slow, and I had to use a mixture of grammar and split. I used to grammar to get "39 3A 3B" as a whole and split it.
`for split(" ", $str) {
$buf.push(:16($_));
}`

Comment: Hi again @tejas. Thanks for the data/code you reddit PMed me. I've replied with code there but noticed your last public reddit comment was months ago so I'm pinging you here to go look there. I look forward to hearing how it performs. :)

Comment: In case it's of use to readers, [@tejas's data/code, and my suggestion as code that worked much faster when I tried it](https://gist.github.com/raiph/e20c54037211dc04b172c50409b7126d).

Answer (score 5):

If you don't need to use grammars, you can do this:

```
my $a = "39 3A 3B  9:;";
say $a.split(/\s+/).grep: * ~~ /<< <[0..9 A..F]> ** 2 >>/;
```

The regex will match these 2-digit hexa strings. Anyway, the problem with your grammar might be in the number of spaces you're using; they are very strict in that sense.

Comment: I do want to use grammar, as this is part of a bigger grammar.

Comment: @tejas you can still use this code as an Action. Anyway, raiph's solution is a good one. Also check out the regex, which will match word-boundary separated hexa figures.