# What's the best way to be lax on whitespace in a perl6 grammar?

Tags: raku

I want to have a grammar that is lax in whether whitespace is present or not... I want to match:

```
this                '   <foo>    <bar>    <baz>    '
and also this       '<foo><bar><baz>'
```

This works:

```
token TOP     { \s* <foo> \s* <bar> \s* <baz> \s* }
```

But after reading all about *:sigspace,* *<.ws>* and *rule* I can imagine that there is a way to do this without the repeated *\s . 
(viz. [How do I match a hex array in per6 grammar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56421909/how-do-i-match-a-hex-array-in-per6-grammar))

Please can someone tell me if there is nicer way to do this in a perl6 grammar?

NB. this is not solved by simply changing the *token* declarator to *rule* - when I try that approach I end up *either* matching space or no space (but not *both*) in the parse string.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Perhaps your problem is one these three rule "gotchyas":

- If you want white space / token boundary matching **at the *start* of a rule, *before* the *first* atom**, you must *explicitly* provide it (typically with an explicit `<.ws>`).
- If you want white space / token boundary matching ***between* each of the matches of a *quantified* atom** (eg `<foo>*`) you must include space between the atom and the quantifier (eg `<foo> *`).
- The default `<ws>` is defined as `regex ws { <!ww> \s* }`. If you want `rule`s in a particular grammar to use a different pattern, then define your own in that grammar. (timotimo++)

For further discussion of the above, see my updated answer to [How do I match a hex array in per6 grammar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56421909/how-do-i-match-a-hex-array-in-per6-grammar).

---

The following four regexes match both your sample strings:

```
my \test-strings := '   <foo>    <bar>    <baz>    ', '<foo><bar><baz>';

my \test-regexes := token { \s*   '<foo>' \s* '<bar>' \s* '<baz>' \s* },
                    rule  { \s*   '<foo>' \s* '<bar>' \s* '<baz>' \s* },
                    rule  { \s*   '<foo>'     '<bar>'     '<baz>'     },
                    rule  { <.ws> '<foo>'     '<bar>'     '<baz>'     }

say (test-strings X~~ test-regexes).all ~~ Match # True
```

Comment: it could also be the case that the default `<ws>` rule requires a word boundary if there is no whitespace, and if it's not literally "<foo>" that is to be matched, but "something", that could be a problem. So defining your own ws to just be `\s*` would do the trick in that case

Comment: thank you @raiph and timotimo for your prompt answers - after some time to try the variations you propose when in a suitable mind state, I conclude I was unable to clearly articulate my problem [I have marked as 'answered' because I think you did a very good job in the situation] for now, since it works for me I will stick to \s*

Comment: PS. I love the X~~ "cross product" & junction

Comment: o/ @p6steve. Thanks for the follow up. I would love to understand what you were driving at. Please feel free to ask another SO or three if you wish and I will gladly have more goes at it. (That said, please consider reading the **Håkon's solution to another likely problem** section in https://stackoverflow.com/a/56998585/1077672 first. I highly doubt it's at all relevant but it's the most explicit answer I've yet written about use of `:sig-space` and worthy of getting out of the way first if you do decide to dig into this again.) PS. I loved the `X~~` too. I made that up for this answer. :)